# I need you to redirect to Shop if url is wrong. React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I need it to redirect to my main page if the url is wrong, the problem must be in this part , because before I used Redirect, but in the new version of React it is Navigate and I don't know if the way of entering changed

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {authRoutes, publicRoutes} from '../routes';
import { SHOP_ROUTE } from '../utils/consts';

const AppRouter = () => {
    const isAuth = false
    return (
        <Routes>
            {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component/>} exact/>
            )}
            {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component/>} exact/>
            )}
            <Navigate to={SHOP_ROUTE}/>
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include a `<Route path="*" />` component (as shown in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#not-found-routes)) at the end of the `<Routes />`, then the last route will be shown when no other route has been matched.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {authRoutes, publicRoutes} from '../routes';
import { SHOP_ROUTE } from '../utils/consts';

const AppRouter = () => {
    const isAuth = false
    return (
        <Routes>
            {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component/>} exact/>
            )}
            {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component/>} exact/>
            )}
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default AppRouter;
```